# Largest power of 2 no larger than a given value

Tags: python, numpy, binary

Looking for something along the lines of:

```
t = 1
get_floor_bin(t)
#1

t = 2
get_floor_bin(t)
#2

t = 3
get_floor_bin(t)
#2

t = 7
get_floor_bin(t)
#4

t = 15
get_floor_bin(t)
#8

t = 16
get_floor_bin(t)
#16
```

My current approach involves creating a list of binary numbers, and searching for each individual closest floor number within the list, but I was wondering if there are more clever approaches.

Thanks!

Comment: Your terminology is unusual. Are you looking for the largest *power of two* that's <= t?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. My terminology is inexact because I'm approaching it concretely and not thinking of binary numbers as a series of powers of 2. My mistake.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this what you need? Your explanation isn't terribly easy to understand.

```
for i in 1, 2, 3, 7, 15, 16:
    print 1 << (i.bit_length() - 1)
```

This gives:

```
1
2
2
4
8
16
```

Comment: Aside from being more elegant, this way is also 3 times faster than the log-based one.

Comment: Just shows it pays to read [NEWS.txt](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r271/Misc/NEWS) (see issue #3439)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `1 << int(math.floor(math.log(x,2)))` will give you the correct result:

```
import math
for x in (1,2,3,7,15,16):
    print x, 1 << int(math.floor(math.log(x,2)))
1 1
2 2
3 2
7 4
15 8
16 16
```

Comment: Fun fact: For `x = (1<<1000) - 1` this incorrectly gives 1<<1000 instead of 1<<999. `(1<<100)-1` works. I didn't search any further, but from my floating point knowledge, I'd expect the errors to start somewhere around 1<<127, give or take a few. This is not a problem for most application, but it's worth keeping in mind in case you ever need numbers with thousands of bits, e.g. for some crypto.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this way is fast enough:

```
In [394]: def largestPower(n):
     ...:     return int('1'+'0'*(len(bin(n))-3), 2)

In [395]: largestPower(15)
Out[395]: 8

In [396]: largestPower(1)
Out[396]: 1

In [397]: largestPower(7)
Out[397]: 4
```